# Why chained mutable state is not updated?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The value of diabledValue is never updated. It always has value "A" How to properly chain mutableStates?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DropDownDemo() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val items = listOf("A", "B", "C", "d", "E", "F")
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var disabledValue by remember { mutableStateOf(items[selectedIndex]) }
    Log.e("mcheck", "$selectedIndex $disabledValue")
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)
    )
    {
        Text(
            items[selectedIndex],
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable(onClick = { expanded = true })
                .background(Color.Gray)
        )
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    selectedIndex = index
                    expanded = false
                }) {
                    var disabledText = if (s == disabledValue) {
                        " Disabled"
                    } else {
                        ""
                    }
                    Text(text = s + disabledText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually don't need `disabledValue` to be `State` or `remember`ed at all, so simply

```kotlin
val disabledValue = items[selectedIndex]
```

is the best thing you can do here. This is because getting item by index from array list is **not expensive**, and your composable has to recompose every time `selectedIndex` changes.

And to answer your question "How to properly chain mutableStates?" - if one of those wouldn't be the case, there is a [`derivedStateOf`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/f6df7df4bb215d31187a32dea874edd43eb9506f:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/DerivedState.kt;l=311) for such cases.

For example, if the calculation is somewhat expensive:

```kotlin
val list = ...
var selectedId by remember { mutableStateOf("...") }
val disabledValue by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        list.find { it.id == selectedId }
    }
}
```

Here, searching in a list is quite expensive calculation. With `derivedStateOf`, it will be done only when `selectedId` is changed. When your composable is recomposed because of some other change, `derivedStateOf` will use cached value and saves you that calculation.

And in this example:

```kotlin
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
val toolbarElevation by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        if (listState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0) 0.dp else 8.dp
    }
}

TopAppBar(
    elevation = toolbarElevation
)
```

`listState.firstVisibleItemIndex` is changing quite often when you scroll, but your composable have to recompose only when it changes from 0 to 1 and vice versa, and that's what `derivedStateOf` does for you.

`derivedStateOf` would also work for your case, but like I said, it's not necessary.

Comment: I'd also add that the original solution would work with slight modification `var disabledValue by remember(selectedIndex) { mutableStateOf(items[selectedIndex]) }`, but this answer is much better